# Displaying multiple pieces of data from a database, and display it in one text box

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, ms-access

I am making a game, and want to display all of a students results in one text box ( or however else it can be done to display it)

In my database, i have a field called username. This adds the same users name as a new record every time a game finishes, containing the score too. The problem is, I can only seem to display the latest score. How would I go about displaying all of the results for one student in one box. Also, how would I seperate them with commas ? Thank you

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
' Accesses my database, and checks whether the teacher is in the database '
Public Class RetrieveResults
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Private Sub Retrieveresults_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "D:\Student Database1.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub

Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.Open()
    surname.Clear()
    Classs.Clear()
    Score.Clear()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM [SCORE] WHERE (Student_UserName = '" & Student_name.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        surname.Text = dr("Student_Username").ToString
        Classs.Text = dr("class").ToString
        Score.Text = dr("score").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: hard to help without code

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  "How do I display data" is generally answered with "by writing code to do that".  What code have you written and where are you stuck?

Comment: sorry, did this on my phone, but now I have the code:

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to use the site effectively.  You need to spend *at least as much time* on your post as you would like in return - formatting code to look like code for instance.  Never, ever glue data and text together to make SQL.  Never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            surname.Clear()
            Classs.Clear()
            Score.Clear()
            Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM [SCORE] WHERE (Student_UserName = @StudentName);"
            Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =D:\Student Database1.accdb")
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Student_name.Text
                    myConnection.Open()
                    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        While dr.Read()
                            Classs.Text &= dr("class").ToString & ", "
                            Score.Text &= dr("score").ToString & ", "
                        End While
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            surName.Text = Student_name.Text
End Sub
```

1. Instead of all the strings I passed the connection string directly in the Connection constructor. I moved the Form level variables to the button event.
2. I used the Using ...End Using statements on the Connection, Command, and DataReader to make sure they are disposed properly even if there is an error.
3. I changed the Select statement to use parameters. Access doesn't care what you call it as long as it add the parameter in the same order as in the SQL statement. Not a problem here since there is only one.
4. I took the surName out of the Whiile loop there should only be one value for this.
5. I added an & before the equals sign so the loop will add the next value to text box and I added the comma to each iteration
   I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! does exactly what I wanted it to!